# Using items in querySelectorAll()

Tags: javascript

I just started learning Javascript and thought it might be a good idea to start with some practical examples.

I know that in Sass I'm able to use the items of list within a loop.

```
$list: item-1, item-2, item-3;

@each $item in $list {
  .#{$item} {
   
  }
}
```

I'm wondering if that is possible in Js too

```
notificationTypes.forEach(function(type) {
  document.querySelectorAll(.type).forEach(function(el) {
```

```
const notificationTypes = ["alert", "info", "succes", "warning"];

notificationTypes.forEach(function(type) {
  document.querySelectorAll(.type).forEach(function(el) {
    ...
  })
})
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(\`.${type}\`).forEach(...)`

Comment: @Yousaf. Thanks! I thought it might be that simple. Voting to close

Comment: @Yousaf. Hmm, still returns an error. *SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.'*

Comment: Answer below did the same thing and its working.

Comment: @Yousaf. Your answer isn't incorrect, but the one below is more accurate since it told me to not only use `.${type}` but \`.${type}\`.

Comment: That is what i suggested. You can use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) or concatenate the `type` with `'.'` --> `'.' + type`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all this array elements as class you can create [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) as an argument. If they are id then insread of dot in template literals use `#`.

Change

```
document.querySelectorAll(.type)
```

to

```
document.querySelectorAll(`.${type}`)
```

```js
const notificationTypes = ["alert", "info", "succes", "warning"];

notificationTypes.forEach(function(type) {
  document.querySelectorAll(`.${type}`).forEach(function(el) {
    console.log(el)
  })
})
```

```css
.alert {
  background: orange;
}

.info {
  background: blue;
}

.succes {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert">1</div>
<div class="info">1</div>
<div class="succes">1</div>
<div class="warning">1</div>
<div class="alert">1</div>
<div class="info">1</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great. So #{$item} is the Sass equivalent to ${type}? Is there something special to the `` brackets or may I use `""`? I'll accept your answer as soon as possible.

Comment: @Simplicius See: [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)